# DXF import to Blender with big Coordinates

Tags: import, coordinates

New to Blender.
I want to import an DXF with big coordinates into Blender, move the Objects to 0 so i can work on them but dont change the orginial Coordinates of the Objects for the Export.

Comment: Blender doesn't handle very high coordinates well. Can't you add your delta from where the dxf came from and remove it after exporting it ?

Comment: What do you mean by adding my delta?  DXF came from AutoCad  btw

Comment: I mean center your object in autocad around 0, 0, 0 and then import it in blender. Then export it as is from blender, and use the opposite of the vector you used to recenter your object in autocad

Comment: I dont want to mess with the objects orignial coordinates as i cant have any errors here.
I thought about something like a temporary second Coordinate system that is assinged to the Objects while in Blender

Comment: What about placing an Empty at 0, 0, 0 and parent it to an object that's off center. Then move the object to 0, 0, 0 which moves the Empty somewhere else. After you finished working on the object you unparent the Empty and instead parent the object to it and move the Empty back to 0, 0, 0. Of course that's tedious. Using Delta Transforms might be easier. Do you want to move a complete collection of DXF objects to the center so that they keep their relative locations to each other or do you want to move each single object to the center on its own?